# How to initiate a transaction with address and privateKey using web3js

Tags: web3js, transactions, accounts

I have a list of ethereum addresses and private keys, I need to write an automation script which checks for the balance in each address and transfer the balance funds to another ethereum address. 
My question is how I perform the fund transfer with address and privateKey using web3js

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to programmatically create transactions for accounts where you have the private key, you can call the [`web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#signtransaction) function to create a transaction using web3.js:

```
web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey [, callback]);
```

This will return a `rawTransaction` string which can be directly sent to the network using [`web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#eth-sendsignedtransaction):

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransactionData [, callback])
```

Getting the balance of the account should be even simpler. Just call [`web3.eth.getBalance`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getbalance) for the public address you have for that account:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(address [, defaultBlock] [, callback])
```

I hope this helps!